# Wikipedia Says So

Tags: riddle

For this riddle, I used the 'random article' button on Wikipedia until I found something that wasn't too obscure. Can you tell me which page I landed on?

Created by the power of Watts
And named for an argument happily settled,
Although it was not the only resulting settlement.
Joseph was able to make his coat first
In a pile of grateful vegetables.

Hint 1:

> I come from where the trail led
> And have nowhere else to go.

Hint 2:

> Don't die of dysentery
> On your way to me.

Hint 3:

> I am a place
> Though not a state.

Hint 4:

> Near me, a place named like a crucible
> But not the one where morbid decorations did hang.

Comment: Your reasoning for every line does not need to be correct. Once someone posts the correct answer and at least some correct reasoning, I will release the actual reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the answer...

> [Amity, Oregon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amity,_Oregon)?

Created by the power of Watts

> "The town was established between 1848 and 1849 by Joseph and Ahio S. Watt, two brothers..."

And named for an argument happily settled,

> "The name "Amity" came from the name of a school that was built by two rival communities after the amicable settlement of a dispute."

Although it was not the only resulting settlement.

> There were other settlements that were created in Oregon as a result of the Oregon Trail.

Joseph was able to make his coat first

> "Joseph established the first woolen mill in Oregon"

In a pile of grateful vegetables.

> Amity is in Yamhill County. Hill = pile and I "Yam" grateful.

Comment: 'grateful' was a reference to how yams are typically served during thanksgiving, but yes! Well done!

Comment: Aaa, that makes sense!

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Love

Created by the power of Watts

> "In the city of good ol' Watts" in Southern California is repeated several times in the lyrics, second only to Los Angeles.  Watts has a lasting impact in American and hip hop culture from  Watts riots of 1965, which were recalled during the 1992 Rodney King riots in Los Angeles

And named for an argument happily settled,

> Tupac Shakur was part of the East Coast-West Coast hip hop rivalry, and as a native New Yorker but part of the West Coast/Death Row Records crew, naming what would be his most popular single after California itself would seem to "happily settle" his allegiance in this feud

Although it was not the only resulting settlement.

> However, Tupac Shakur would be killed (which is a kind of not-happy "settlement") as part of the broader rivalries and violence of the various personalities orbiting hip hop music in the mid 1990s.  Tupac himself died because he was in record promoter Suge Knight's entourage the evening a Compton gang attempted to kill Knight (but did kill Shakur)

Joseph was able to make his coat first

> The first sample noted in the Wikipedia article's paragraph on included samples states "The original version contains a sample taken from Joe Cocker's 1972 song "Woman to Woman"."  As the production of the 1996 single California Love comes after this 1991 case which fundamentally altered sampling in hip hop music (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Upright_Music,_Ltd._v._Warner_Bros._Records_Inc. which specifically refers to the impact on Dr Dre) I can safely assert the sampled artist Joe Cocker precleared the sample and got paid before the artists

In a pile of grateful vegetables.

> The Wikipedia article states it was "intended for Dr. Dre's shelved album The Chronic II" where "chronic" is another term for marijuana, weed, herb, etc - all vegetable, and often in a pile.

Comment: No, but I appreciate the amount of thought that you put into it!

Answer (score 4):

Partial, unsure answer:

> It's a place or event in the US dating back to the colonial era. It is somehow tied to people named Watts and Joseph, and is also connected to Thanksgiving. Here's my reasoning:

Created by the power of Watts

> I'm guessing this is someone's last name. If it were referring to "watts" as in electricity it'd be lowercase.

And named for an argument happily settled,

> Probably a conflict between Native Americans and European settlers.

Although it was not the only resulting settlement.

> The modern-day US was gradually settled as Europeans spread throughout the continent.

Joseph was able to make his coat first

> Not sure about the coat, no idea here.

In a pile of grateful vegetables.

> Thanksgiving.

I'll keep thinking.

EDIT: Confirmed incorrect by OP.

> The Treaty of Mortefontaine? Sailor John Watts was a participant in the Quasi-War of 1798 - 1800 that culminated in this settlement, remembered for his success in fighting off a French privateer squad. This treaty marked the end of the Quasi-War, an armed conflict between the US and France. Of course, the US would see plenty of peace treaties in the future. Joseph Bonaparte was one of the men who signed the agreement.

EDIT 2: Also incorrect.

> Is it Watts' West Indies and Virginia expedition? Financed by John Watts, the British merchant and explorer. The Anglo-Spanish War was officially settled in the treaty of London.I feel like this one is much more of a stretch than my previous attempt, but it's worth a shot.

EDIT 3: Another partial answer.

Hint 1 & Hint 2

> Seem to refer to the place in question being at the end of the Oregon trail.

Hint 3

> Yeah, it's a place.

Hint 4

> May refer to Salem, Oregon (not to be confused with Salem, Massachusetts, where lots of people were hanged due to superstition). This leads me to think that the place in question is somewhere in Oregon.

I think I've narrowed in on what the answer may be.

> It's somewhere in or near the Tualatin Mountains. Joseph refers to Joseph Meek, a fur trapper/hunter who definitely made coats and explored the place. The 'argument' that was settled is likely the Oregon Treaty, between the US and other powers.

I'll keep thinking and update if I get any new ideas.

> I'll take a relatively reasonable guess... Oregon City, Oregon?

Comment: Incorrect, but nevertheless well done! Closest answer so far. Pay more attention to your partial answer than your actual answer though.

Comment: Good attempt, but still no.

Answer (score 2):

Is the article about

> Technicolor?

Created by the power of Watts

> It’s a motion picture device that used electricity

And named for an argument happily settled,

> Looks like a portmanteau word of sorts...

Although it was not the only resulting settlement.

> More moviemaking techniques were created

Joseph was able to make his coat first

> Joseph and the Amazing Technicolor Dreamcoat?

In a pile of grateful vegetables.

> 

Comment: Thanks for falling for all of the traps that I left in there :)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb

*Created by the power of Watts*

> Lightbulbs run on power and their consumption is measured in Watts

*And named for an argument happily settled,*

> Incandescent also means "full of strong emotion; passionate."

*Although it was not the only resulting settlement.*

> There have been disputes around the owner/inventor

*Joseph was able to make his coat first*

> Joseph Swan helped to pioneer the filament ('coat') so that they lasted longer

*In a pile of grateful vegetables.*

> Not 100% sure on this one...

Comment: No, sorry. You fell for a couple of the tricks laid in the riddle.

Answer (score 2):

Could it possibly be:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joy_to_the_World

Created by the power of Watts

> The lyrics for *Joy to the World* were written by Isaac Watts

And named for an argument happily settled,

> Said argument has to do with the coming of Jesus Christ as King, and of his resulting triumph over sin in this world.

Although it was not the only resulting settlement.

> The current version of the music was written by Lowell Mason, who claimed he had adapted it from Handel, although Handel scholars claim that the similarities are chance.

Joseph was able to make his coat first

> This hymn was adapted by W.W. Phelps for *A Collection of Sacred Hymns*, which is the hymnal for the Latter Day Saints. The Latter Day Saints, of course, were founded by Joseph Smith.

In a pile of grateful vegetables.

> The song has been performed in the children's show *Veggie Tales*.

Since the first one didn't do it, let's look at this:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Kearny

Created by the power of Watts

> Named for Colonel (later General) Steven Watts Kearny

And named for an argument happily settled,

> The second Fort Kearny was originally named Fort Childs, but the War Department ordered that it be renamed Fort Kearny.

Although it was not the only resulting settlement.

> Oooh, "settlement." I just got that. Dobytown and a number of "road ranches" were built up nearby.

Joseph was able to make his coat first

> Once again, we see the Latter Day Saints, this time because Fort Kearny was on the Mormon trail and Lt. Daniel P. Woodbury advocated the use of Mormon emigrants for construction.

In a pile of grateful vegetables.

> The fort kept a large number of supplies on hand for travelers, and the commander was instructed to sell these goods at cost, or even provide them for free, for which the travelers would obviously be grateful.

And, of course, the hints...

> I remember playing *The Oregon Trail* on an Apple IIe back in junior high school, about (coughhackcrunch) years ago.

Comment: I love this answer and I almost wish it were correct! +1

Comment: Man, that's probably it. I'd be surprised if there's anything else that fits all the descriptors.

Comment: You are so close (and in the correct country), keep at it! I'll add another hint