# Wikipedia Says So #2

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

Previous puzzle of this kind: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75053/wikipedia-says-so)

> A bird without wing, body, feet or tail,
>   An invention am I who can effortlessly sail.
>   I am unlike my lowly brothers who only deliver mail;
>   Surging over the winds I am majestic without fail!
>
> ...Alas, that is a lie, I do have one shortcoming
>   In order to be useful to you I cannot be made thin.
>   Thanks a lot, you, you darned and cursed thing!
>   Now there are barriers I shan't break, oh, races I'll never win!
>
> You say that there's a Wikipedia article for anything?
>   Find mine, then, and declare yourself this puzzle's king!

Hint 1:

> My stability was an issue that my creators did see
> That is the reason why they taught me to sweep.

Hint 2:

> UFOs have a generic shape;
> I do too, though not from space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you?

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_wing

A bird without wing, body, feet or tail,
An invention am I who can effortlessly sail.

> Aircraft, plane or drone

I am unlike my lowly brothers who only deliver mail;
Surging over the winds I am majestic without fail!

...Alas, that is a lie, I do have one shortcoming
In order to be useful to you I cannot be made thin.

> Needs to have room for engines, fuel, cabin inside the wing.

Thanks a lot, you, you darned and cursed thing!
Now there are barriers I shan't break, oh, races I'll never win!

> Will never break the sound barrier. Too thick to hold the equipment.

You say that there's a Wikipedia article for anything?
Find mine, then, and declare yourself this puzzle's king!

Comment: Correct! Green checkmark and bounty are yours once you come up with a better explanation for the '...Alas' line. It's closely tied to the line directly after.

Comment: Updated to explain correctly

Comment: That has wings... (it’s even in the answer: “needs to have room for engines, fuel, cabin, inside the wing”)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a

> Kite?

Paragraph 1

> Kites soar through the air but do not have the anatomical parts of a bird. They are also an invention.

and

> Kites have many purposes, from recreation to meteorology to military. Maybe its 'brother' refers to the mail pigeon.

Paragraph 2

> A kite needs ample wingspan to stay afloat. (cannot be thin)

The clues also kind of sound like a

> Balloon, for mostly the same reasons.

Comment: Just looked at the previous wikipedia question and it seems like the correct solution is supposed to be decently obscure.

Comment: obscurity isn't the goal, but the 'random article' feature tends to make it so; I stuck with one of the least obscure ones I found. You're headed in the right direction, keep it up!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I took a decent sized shoehorn, and with its help, I worked on

> [HMS Warrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Warrior_(1860))

until it seemed it might fit:

A bird without wing, body, feet or tail,

> HMS warrior is a frigate, which is also [a bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frigatebird)

An invention am I who can effortlessly sail.

> A steam powered ship

I am unlike my lowly brothers who only deliver mail;

> HMS stands for "Her Majesty's Ship", the other well known ship prefix RMS means "Royal Mail Steamer"

Surging over the winds I am majestic without fail!

> A steam ship can sail against the wind

...Alas, that is a lie, I do have one shortcoming
In order to be useful to you I cannot be made thin.

> HMS Warrior was an Ironclad (one of the first), so it had to have a thick armour.

Thanks a lot, you, you darned and cursed thing!

> The armour was needed because of wars.

Now there are barriers I shan't break, oh, races I'll never win!

> While the ship isn't actually very slow by any means, it definitely isn't the fastest either.

Comment: Good try. Combine answers with @1848

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

> some kind of war plane?

A bird without wing, body, feet or tail,

> again, they don't have the anatomy of a bird but fly like one

An invention am I who can effortlessly sail.

> it's an invention, and sails in the sky

I am unlike my lowly brothers who only deliver mail;

> mail planes

Surging over the winds I am majestic without fail!

> literally flies over the winds

...Alas, that is a lie, I do have one shortcoming

In order to be useful to you I cannot be made thin.

> the planes need to be heavily armored

Thanks a lot, you, you darned and cursed thing!
Now there are barriers I shan't break, oh, races I'll never win!

> because of said armor, the plane is slower, so it won't win a race to a faster plane

Comment: Closest answer so far, but no cigar

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a

> Zeppelin

A bird without wing, body, feet or tail

> A zeppelin has no wings etc.

An invention am I who can effortlessly sail

> A zeppelin has motors and doesn't need wind.

I am unlike my lowly brothers who only deliver mail

> Zeppelins were used in wars to drop bombs.

...Alas, that is a lie, I do have one shortcoming
In order to be useful to you I cannot be made thin

> A zeppelin is filled with some sort of gas to fly, and even unfilled it has a predefined shape.

Now there are barriers I shan't break, oh, races I'll never win!

> Zeppelins are no longer really used.

Comment: A little bit farther from the answer than Excited Raichu