# Wikipedia Says So #3

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, limerick

Previous puzzles in series: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75053/wikipedia-says-so), [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75297/wikipedia-says-so-2)

> A reference to the order to cite
>   The works of those who write
>   And star and edit
>   And even more get credit!
>   It's about the boring part of the night.

Hint 1:

> The studio comes first! The company second!
> I am master of performance credits right until the end!

Hint 2:

> Credits themselves are so narrow in scope;
> With plays and more performing arts I elope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the page...

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billing_(filmmaking)?
> Guess #2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_(creative_arts)
> Guess #1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits

A reference to the order to cite

> "The order in which credits are billed generally signify their importance. While there are numerous variations, most opening credits use some variation of the following basic order..."

The works of those who write

> Credits usually have who the screenwriters and songwriters are.

And star and edit

> They also list the actors and production crew

And even more get credit!

> They usually list everyone that was involved in the movie or whatever the credits were for.

It's about the boring part of the night.

> Usually people go to see movies at night and the end credits are generally the most boring part.

Hint 1

> There is a billing order which starts with the studio, followed by the production company. Also, "Billing is a performing arts term used in referring to the order and other aspects of how credits are presented for plays, films, television, or other creative works."

Comment: Very, very close

Comment: @kanoo I changed the page. Is that one correct?

Comment: No, if I were you I would pay particular attention to the first line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably wrong but is it;

> Guess 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_persons_fictitious_disclaimer
> Guess 1: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits#References
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtain_call

A reference to the order to cite:

> Most films absolutely have to have an APF disclaimer.

The works of those who write:

> The familiar disclaimer is often rewritten for humor. Early examples include The Three Stooges' parody of Nazi Germany "You Nazty Spy", which stated that "Any resemblance between the characters in this picture and any persons, living or dead, is a miracle," and its sequel "I'll Never Heil Again", which features a disclaimer that states that "The characters in this picture are fictitious. Anyone resembling them is better off dead."

And star and edit:

> Stars are the main purpose of the APF disclaimer and it is usually the editors job to edit the APF disclaimer in.

And even more get credit:

> The APF disclaimer, although mainly referring to stars, also includes all actors and extras.

It's about the boring part of the night:

> APF disclaimers are dodecaboring. Unless it's comedic such as An American Werewolf In London.

Also I really like the way you made it rhyme, good job!

And the second and third guesses aren't really my best idea...

Comment: Make sure to include explanation/reasoning for answers

Comment: There we go. I did it.

Comment: No, sorry. As in the previous puzzles, I am talking about an entire Wikipedia page. In case it helps anyone, I'm not only referring to movies.

Comment: @kanoo I made a new answer, is this one right? It's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I suggest you pay extra attention to the word 'order' in the first line. I am not referring to the thing itself like credits or curtain call but I am referring to something that governs both, almost like a set of rules.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

> Thinking about boring part of the night, and how ridiculously long it can get a wild guess would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acknowledgment_(creative_arts_and_sciences). Not sure how it can be explained by other clues, but maybe it connects with first line as citations in science works, which have strict order.

I think it is (with @JR_M help):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_credits It can't be closing credits, because 'In the absence of opening credits, these roles will often be credited in reverse order at the beginning of the closing credits'

A reference to the order to cite

> While there are numerous variations most opening credits use some variation of the basic order.

The works of those who write
And star and edit
And even more get credit!

> lists the most important members of the production.

The studio comes first! The company second!

> Basic order states, that studio comes first, then the company

Comment: Welcome to PSE! I specifically wrote that 'credits are so narrow in scope' in one of the hints, so this is not the answer.

Comment: @kanoo thought again about whole thing and edited.

Answer (score -4):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billing_(filmmaking) 
>  Refers more specifically to the proper order in which to give credit, it is the *rules* regarding credits or its theater equivalent, the abstract of each of the answers given previously. It is to the credits what a citation format is to a bibliography.

Comment: Someone already gave this answer, you could've accepted it as the correct one instead of posting the answer yourself (repeated)

Comment: @S.M. My apologies. I think that I saw that answer before it was edited and was never notified.